# Add a menu item within a menu within a menu item in JAVA

Tags: java

```
applicationMenu.add(subapplicationMenu);
    subapplicationMenu.add(item);
    subapplicationMenu.add(item1);
    subapplicationMenu.add(item2);


    item.add(item3);
    item.add(item4);
    item.add(item5);
    item.add(item6);
    item.add(item7);
    item.add(item8);
    item.add(item9);
    item.add(item10);
    item.add(item11);

    item1.add(item3);
    item1.add(item4);
    item1.add(item5);
    item1.add(item6);
    item1.add(item7);
    item1.add(item8);
    item1.add(item9);
    item1.add(item10);
    item1.add(item11);

    item2.add(item3);
    item2.add(item4);
    item2.add(item5);
    item2.add(item6);
    item2.add(item7);
    item2.add(item8);
    item2.add(item9);
    item2.add(item10);
    item2.add(item11);
```

I'm trying to add a menu item within a menu item within a menu item but it will not allow me to there are no errors it just will not show up when trying to access the third level of menu items.

Comment: It's a standard JMenu it doesn't matter subapplicationMenu or items can be = to anything. The task is your ability to create a menu within a menu within a menu

Comment: it doesn't matter? if item1, item2 are Integers, I've found your problem. If you're using a null layout manager, I've found your problem. If you're running this code on a toaster etc. We need some context here or we're flying blind, and then **you** are the person best equipped to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest JMenu within other instances of JMenu, and you can add a JMenuItem to a JMenu, but you can't add a JMenuItem to another JMenuItem. Think about that... what did you expect that to do? A leaf, for example, grows from a branch, not from another leaf.

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Main Menu");

JMenu submenu = new JMenu("A menu within a menu");

JMenu subsubmenu = new JMenu("A menu within a menu within a menu");

JMenuItem itemFoo = new JMenuItem("Foo");
JMenuItem itemBar = new JMenuItem("Bar");
JMenuItem itemBaz = new JMenuItem("Baz");
JMenuItem itemQuz = new JMenuItem("Quz");

// These are OK

menu.add(subMenu);
subMenu.add(subsubmenu);
subMenu.add(itemFoo);
subMenu.add(itemBar);
subMenu.add(itemBaz);

// NO!

itemBaz.add(itemQuz);
```

Review the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

Comment: @JLong You're welcome. Click the checkmark to the left of the answer to let people know which answer helped you.

Comment: I already got you covered it is possible for you to take a look at my .read error question I posted & provide me with assistance.

Comment: @JLong Sure, I can look at the other question, but go ahead and click the grey checkmark next to this answer to show that you've accepted it. You haven't accepted it yet.

Comment: I did but they stated this: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.